# Issue regarding images in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating an E-commerce website in which I had to create one big responsive and 5 small product images in the product page just like in Amazon or Flipkart. I know the class="img-responsive" is for responsive image class in bootstrap but it's not working in my case.When I open the site in other devices the main big image getting more bigger(not being responsive) and all small images are coming on to the big one. [Image on the big screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ftg5.png) [Image on the mobile device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VXYp.png) and also I'm getting more confuse with the the media queries on working with the images.

Below is my html,css and Js please help me out if I have done anything wrong.

This is my Javascript

```
 var images = document.getElementById("mydiv").getElementsByTagName("img"); 
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) 
{ 
images[i].onmouseover = function () { 
this.style.cursor = 'hand'; 
this.style.borderColor = 'red'; 
} 
images[i].onmouseout = function () { 
this.style.cursor = 'pointer'; 
this.style.borderColor = 'grey'; 
} 
} 
function productImage(event)
{
    event= event || window.event;

    var targetElement= event.target || event.srcElement;
    if(targetElement.tagName == "IMG")
    {
        mainImage.src = targetElement.getAttribute("src");
    }
}
```

This is my HTML

```
<div class="col-md-7 showcase1">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 main-img">
                        <img id="mainImage" src="Tiger.jpg"  class="img-responsive" alt=" No Image">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="mydiv" onclick= "productImage(event)">
                    <div class="row sub-image-row">
                        <div class="col-xs-2 sub-img" >
                             <img src="Tiger.jpg"  class="img-responsive "  alt=" No Image"> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-2 sub-img">
                             <img src="Lion.jpg"  class="img-responsive"  alt=" No Image"> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-2 sub-img">
                             <img src="Tiger.jpg" class="img-responsive"  alt=" No Image"> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-2 sub-img">  
                             <img src="Tiger.jpg"  class="img-responsive"   alt=" No Image"> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-2 sub-img">
                             <img src="Tiger.jpg" class="img-responsive"  alt=" No Image"> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
```

This is my CSS

```
.showcase1,.main-img,.sub-img{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
.main-img{
    width:700px;
    height:400px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    //border:1px solid black;
}
.main-img img{
    max-height:400px;
}
.sub-img{

    width:110px;
    height:110px;
    margin:5px;
    border-radius:1px;  
}
.sub-img img{
    max-width:110px;
    max-height:110px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
@media  (max-width: 400px) {
    .main-img{
        height:220px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap 3 or 4? In V4 the class is called `img-fluid`

Comment: I'm still in V3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are giving .main-img a set height, while the image inside is responsive and has an auto height. So when you move to a smaller screen, the image has a larger height than the 220px you set in your media query. If you really do want it to have a height of 220px on that size of screen, you will need to set the max height of the image in that media query as well.

Comment: Now it's working fine. I've removed the media query which I don't need and set the height to max-height to the div .main-img. Thankyou

Comment: But still, as i removed the fixed div size when the image changes in the div, the div size also changes and it pushes down the five images below.Which I'm not happy with.